# I cant import json in angular2

Tags: angular

When I import in my `.ts` component file a `.json` it says me Cannot find module `../../util/provinces.json`. Consider using `--resolveJsonModule` to import module with `.json` extensionts (2732).
How can I import a .json file with angular2? [Ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1u6h.png)

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json` set `resolveJsonModule` to `true`

Comment: Did you follow what the compiler suggested?

Comment: I have several files: tsconfig.json, tsconfigapp.json, tsconfigspec.json but they doesnt have resolveJsonModule option

Answer (score 0):

You only need to go to your tsconfig.json in the root of your angular project, then add a new line:
"resolveJsonModule": true,

Comment: When i did that a new error appeared: Error: tsconfig.json(12,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.

Comment: Oh, you must be actually using Angular version 2. ResolveJsonModule is a feature of Angular7 via TypeScript 3. To import JSON files in older versions of Angular/TS you have to make a http request

Answer (score 0):

With Angular before version 7/ Typescript before version 3, you must make an http request to read JSON, even for local files. Upgrade to Angular7 and TS3 for resolveJsonModule, or read up on making http requests.

Comment: how can i use a http request

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with a json-typings.d.ts in src folder

`declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
  }`
and then in my component 
`import * as SampleJson from '../../../assets/province.json';`

the json has been imported in assest